# Proving a group with prime order has to be cyclic and has no nontrivial subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question about the proof of some facts. We have a group $G$ and its order is a prime number, let's say $p$. I know this group has to be cyclic and $G$ has no nontrivial subgroups. But how can I prove these facts?

Answer (score 1):

You should be familiar with the Lagrange theorem, stating that the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group.

For the second question, by the Lagrange theorem, the order of any subgroup must divide $p$ which is a prime, so the order must be 1 or $p$, so the subgroup is trivial.

To prove that G is cyclic, take any element $g\not=1$. The set $\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a subgroup so, by the second question, it must be trivial i.e. $\langle g\rangle=1$ or $\langle g\rangle=G$. But since $g\in \langle g\rangle$ and $g\not=1$ it must be $\langle g\rangle=G$, so g is a generator.